# Fitness Exercise Database / API

Tags: api, sports

Im looking for a online database / API where i can pull information about some fitness exercises with basic information like difficulty, name, how to do it, etc. I hope you get my point. I saw one question about this topic but i couldn't find any good results with the answers that were postet there so i thought i ask a new question with the faith that someone got something "newer" for me. appreciate any help :)

Comment: Hmmm.. it seems like USDA has most of the data you are looking for encapsulated in their `SuperTracker` tool at https://www.supertracker.usda.gov/physicalactivitytracker.aspx -- I would consider contacting them to see about getting the data behind this tool.

Answer (score 1):

If scraping* is a possibility, [ExRx](https://exrx.net/) has hosted a well-structured exercise website for a long time (19 years!)

From the [Exercise Directory](https://exrx.net/Lists/Directory), each muscle group is clearly listed. For example, [Upper Arm](https://exrx.net/Lists/ExList/ArmWt).

Each exercise is also clearly listed, for example, [Tricepts](https://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Triceps/ASTriDip).

In the HTML source of each page, you'll also see pretty clearly the text and images/videos that you may want to collect. For example:

[image]

---

*Depending on your use case, web-scraping may or may not be a useful way to collect and use data.*

Comment: From their terms: "Automated scraping or manual copying of content is prohibited"

Answer (score 1):

Wger seems to provide [an API](https://wger.de/en/software/api) for this, complete with info about the muscles exercised and the equipment needed.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like it offers an extensive repository of exercises.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/yuhonas/free-exercise-db has around 800 exercises and can be downloaded as JSON.

https://rapidapi.com/justin-WFnsXH_t6/api/exercisedb/ also exists but it's behind a paywall after 400 requests each month.